# Allocating structs of arbitrary constant size on the stack

Tags: c++, casting, shared-libraries, move-semantics, alloca

I've written a small working plugin server. The plugins are implemented using `.so` shared objects, which are manually loaded during runtime in the "server" by calls to `dlopen` (header `<dlfcn.h>`).

All of the shared object plugins have the same interface:

```cpp
extern "C" void* do_something() {
    return SharedAllocator<T>{}.allocate(...); // new T
}
extern "C" size_t id = ...; // unique
```

- Basically, `do_something` returns a pointer to heap memory, that the caller is expected to free.
- `id` is simply an identifier unique per `.so`.
- `T` is a struct specific to each `.so`. Some of them share the same return type, some of them don't. The point here is, `sizeof(T)` is `.so` specific.

The server is in charge of dynamically loading and reading the symbols of the `.so` binaries. All `.so` plugins can call each other through a method `do_something_proxy` defined in the server binary, which acts as the glue between the callers and the callees:

```cpp
extern "C" void* do_something_proxy(size_t id) {
    // find the requested handle
    auto handle = some_so_map.find(id)->second;

    // call the handle's `do_something`
    void* something_done = handle.do_something();

    // forward the result
    return something_done;
}
```

To simplify things a bit, let's say that `some_so_map` is a plain `std::unordered_map<size_t, so_handle_t>` filled using a bunch of calls to `dlopen` when the proxy is executed.

My issue is that every caller of `do_something_proxy` knows `T` at compile time. As I said earlier, `T` can vary from call site to call site; however `T` *never* changes for an arbitrary call site.

For reference, here's the definition *all* callers use:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t id>
T* typed_do_soemthing_proxy() {
    // simple cast of the proxy
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(do_soemthing_proxy(id));
}
```

In other words, `do_something_proxy` for some arbitrary plugin `id` always has the same return type.

If it wasn't for the proxy, I could just template `do_soemthing_proxy` and pass `T` or an `std::array<int8_t, N>` with `sizeof(T) == N`, and the unnecessary memory allocated to ensure `T` is not sliced when calling `do_something_proxy` could be moved to the stack. However, the proxy cannot be aware of all possible return types during compile time and export a zillion versions of `do_something_proxy`.

**So my question is**, is there any way for `do_soemthing_proxy` to allocate the effective size of `T` on its stack (i.e. using `alloca` or some other form of stack allocation)?

As far as I can tell, `alloca` doesn't seem to work here, as `do_soemthing_proxy` can only receive a single value from the `do_something` function of the requested plugin. `do_soemthing_proxy` would receive both the size to allocate, and the bytes to copy to the allocated memory, at the same time. If only `alloca` could be "squished" in between...

I know I could allocate a fixed amount of memory on the stack using an `std::array<int8_t, N>` with 256 or even 1024 for values of `N`. However, this solution is a bit dirty. It unnecessarily copies data from one stackframe to another, and limits the amount of data that a plugin can return. To top it off, (while I haven't benchmarked this solution yet) unless compilers can elide copies across dynamic boundaries, I'd assume copying 1024 bytes is more work than copying i.e. `sizeof(std::string)` bytes.

In an ideal world, I believe `do_soemthing_proxy` should return a struct that handles this with RAII. A `const std::any` that is stack-allocated, if you will. Is this even possible?

If this is not possible at all within c++, would it possible to achieve this behavior in a portable manner in assembly, i.e. by hijacking the stack or base pointers manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just found a solution. It boils down to inverting the direction in which the memory location for the allocation of `T` is passed around.

> Is there any way for `do_soemthing_proxy` to allocate the effective size of `T` on its stack?

Maybe. But what the code actually needs is an allocation of the effective size of `T` at the caller's location, not inside the proxy. And since the caller knows `sizeof(T)`, all you have to do is allocate the space for `T` on the stack of the caller *before* calling `do_something`, and then pass the address of the allocated buffer to `do_something_proxy` when calling it:

For the caller:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t id>
T typed_do_something_proxy() {
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> return_buffer;
    do_something_proxy(id, &return_buffer);
    return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&return_buffer));
}
```

For the proxy:

```cpp
extern "C" void do_something_proxy(size_t id, void* return_buffer) {
    auto handle = some_so_map.find(id)->second;
    handle.do_something(return_buffer);
}
```

For the callee

```cpp
extern "C" void do_something(void* return_buffer) {
    new(return_buffer) T(...); // placement new
}
```

Comment: The solution -- `typed_do_soemthing_proxy()` makes the copy you wanted to avoid.

Comment: @EmployedRussian it copies a pointer currently yes. However, it seems to me that the data pointed to by `return_buffer` is initialized a single time, at the correct location (i.e. in the caller's stack frame)

Comment: @eerorika is the implementation using std::aligned_storage and std::launder any better?

Comment: @Louis-JacobLebel Seems good.

Comment: What can you actually _do_ with the returned pointer when the aligned storage object has gone out of scope, though?

Comment: @Useless isn't `return_buffer` just copied out to the direct location where `typed_do_soemthing_proxy` is called? I don't see any pointers returned in the solution I proposed

Comment: You're absolutely right, I simply misread your code. Time for a break!